# Proof: GCD divisibility

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I am not sure how to start this proof:

For positive $h, i, j ∈ Z$, prove that if $j = gcd(h, i)$ then $j^2| hi$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$j = gcd(h,i)$ $\implies$ $j|h$ and $j|i$

$j|h$ $\implies$ $\exists$ $a \in \mathbb Z$ such that $h = aj$

$j|i$ $\implies$ $\exists$ $b \in \mathbb Z$ such that $i = bj$

Then:

$hi = (aj)(bj) = (ab)j^2$

But $a \in \mathbb Z$ and $b \in \mathbb Z$ $\implies$ $ab \in \mathbb Z$

Thus, $hi = (ab)j^2$ with $ab \in \mathbb Z$, and so $j^2|hi$

Comment: $j|h$ and $j|i$ so then $j^2|hi$?

Comment: Yes, but you would have to prove that in formal terms. $j|h \implies$ $\exists$ $\alpha$ $\in \mathbb Z$ such that $h = \alpha j$, etc.

Comment: yeah that is that part that confuses me

Comment: Okay. I'll write a formal proof.

Comment: thanks so much. that was really helpful

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\,d\mid h,i\,\Rightarrow\, d^2\mid hi\, $ since $\, (d\bar h)(d\bar i) = d^2 (\bar h\bar i)$

More generally $\ c\mid h,\ d\mid i\,\Rightarrow\,cd\mid hi\ $ with similar proof,

and, furthermore $\ c,d \mid h,i\,\Rightarrow\, {\rm lcm}(c,d)\mid \gcd(h,i)\ $.

All prove handy.